# JavaScript wrong if...else logic

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. There is something wrong with the code as even when the input like abc56, it still alert "Enter your name". Or when the input is abc, it should be displayed "Perfect" instead of "Enter your name". The input only allows characters not number and I think the regex is correct, the only wrong is the logic. Can you guys help me?

```js
var check=document.forms["check"]["name"].value;
var reg=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
function ipt(){
    if(check !== ""){
        if(check.match(reg)===false){
            alert("Only enter character please");
        }
        else{
          alert("Perfect");
        }
      
    }
    else{
        alert("Enter your name");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Check</title>
        <script src="./check.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="check" onsubmit="ipt()">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your !== “” needs to be changed to !== “ “ or null.  If your checking it is empty or even undefined

Comment: After I changed "" to " ", it always shows up "Only enter character please" even when the input contains only character, not number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get  the value of document.forms["check"]["name"]  **on page load**.
not the value onsubmit event

and your regex usage is wrong, use [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
it return a boolean value ( true or false)

do

```
const name_elm = document.forms.check.name
  ,   reg      = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/
  ;
function ipt() {
  if (!!name_elm.value)   // or if (name_elm.value !== '')
  {
    if (reg.test(name_elm.value))
      { alert('Perfect') } 
    else 
      { alert('Only enter character please') }
  } 
  else {
    alert('Enter your name');
} }
```

Comment: The code did not solve the problem as when the input is abc67, it still show up "Perfect"

Comment: Thank god it works now, but I don't under stand why you added !reg.test(checkEl.value)?

Comment: @BeefNoodle Ok, I do the reverse case on this if

Comment: @BeefNoodle `String.prototype.match()` return an Array, it is a bad idea to use it for a test

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up the if statement by using an else if.

When you check for a value in a form, use `value` when you need to see what the current value is.

```js
var check = document.forms["check"]["name"];
var reg = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
function ipt(){
    // check if its empty
    if (check.value === "") {
      alert("Enter your name");
    // check if it matches the pattern
    } else if (!check.value.match(reg)) {
      alert("Only enter character please");
    } else {
      // Success! 
      alert("Perfect");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Check</title>
        <script src="./check.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="check" onSubmit="return ipt()">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```